# Why my app using destroy instead custom action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new at Ruby. Sorry for my English.

I need to create button for destroying all users objects (model named Relations and ListRelations).

This is part of my config/routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }
  resources :relations
  resources :list_relations
  delete '/relations/destroy_member_data' => 'relations#destroy_member_data'
```

relations_controller.rb

```
  def destroy_member_data
    if current_user.relations.destroy_all && current_user.list_relations.destroy_all
      redirect_to(relations_path, :notice => 'All relations were successfully destroyed')
    else
      redirect_to(relations_path, :warning => 'Something went wrong. Please, try again.')
    end
  end
```

relations/index.html.slim:

```
= link_to 'Destroy all data', relations_destroy_member_data_path, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}
```

When I click to this link, I have this error:

```
Couldn't find Relation with 'id'=destroy_member_data

Extracted source (around line #59):

58: def destroy
59:    @relation = Relation.find(params[:id])
```

Can anyone help me? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `/relations/destroy_member_data` matches the delete route for `/relations/:id`, `destroy_member_data` is seen as the id and this route is defined before

Two ways to solve this

- Move that custom route before `resources :relations`
- This should work too and it's cleaner

```
resources :relations do
  delete :destroy_member_data, on: :collection
end
```